# Getting the top 6 items in a column to pivot to a row in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm having trouble getting a column to pivot in SQL. I'd like to pivot the top 6 results from one column into a row. The column I'm pivoting can have less than or more than 6 results to start with but I want to ignore anything beyond the top 6.

My Table1 looks like this:

```
ID | GroupID | CodeNum
----------------------
1  | 1       | 111
2  | 1       | 222
3  | 1       | 333
4  | 1       | 444
5  | 1       | 555
6  | 1       | 666
7  | 1       | 777
8  | 2       | 111
9  | 2       | 888
10 | 3       | 999
```

And I want my output to look like this:

```
GroupID | Code1 | Code2 | Code3 | Code4 | Code5 | Code6
-------------------------------------------------------
1       | 111   | 222   | 333   | 444   | 555   | 666
2       | 111   | 888   |       |       |       |
3       | 999   |       |       |       |       |
```

I've tried this code:

```
SELECT  GroupID
        , [Code1] = CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CodeNum END
        , [Code2] = CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CodeNum END
        , [Code3] = CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CodeNum END
        , [Code4] = CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN CodeNum END
        , [Code5] = CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN CodeNum END
        , [Code6] = CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN CodeNum END
FROM    (
            SELECT  TOP 6 GroupID
                    , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID)
                    , CodeNum
            FROM    Table1      
        ) q
GROUP BY
        GroupID
```

But I'm getting an error that says `Column 'q.rn' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Is there a way to do this when CodeNum could have between 1 and 12 values per GroupID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using a `GROUP BY`, you will need to group by all items in the `SELECT` or use an aggregate function.

You will want to use the following which will get the result and then *pivot* the rows into columns:

```
SELECT  GroupID
        , [Code1] = max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN CodeNum END)
        , [Code2] = max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN CodeNum END)
        , [Code3] = max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN CodeNum END)
        , [Code4] = max(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN CodeNum END)
        , [Code5] = max(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN CodeNum END)
        , [Code6] = max(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN CodeNum END)
FROM    
(
  SELECT  GroupID
   , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID)
   , CodeNum
  FROM    Table1      
) q
GROUP BY GroupID
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba45d/6)

You will notice that I removed the `TOP 6` and added a `partition by GroupId`. If you use the `TOP`, then you will only return the values for the first ID. The partition will return the rows for each ID, but the outer select is only returning the first 6 rows.

This gives the result:

```
| GROUPID | CODE1 |  CODE2 |  CODE3 |  CODE4 |  CODE5 |  CODE6 |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|       1 |   111 |    222 |    333 |    444 |    555 |    666 |
|       2 |   111 |    888 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
|       3 |   999 | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) | (null) |
```

Note, depending on your version of SQL Server, this could also be written using the `PIVOT` function:

```
select GroupID,
  [1] as Code1, 
  [2] as Code2, 
  [3] as Code3, 
  [4] as Code4, 
  [5] as Code5, 
  [6] as Code6
from
(
  SELECT  GroupID
   , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupID ORDER BY ID)
   , CodeNum
  FROM Table1    
) d
pivot
(
  max(codenum)
  for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) piv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba45d/11)