# Dynamic Pivot of multi-columns based on rank of row Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dynamic, pivot

I have data as below :

[image]

and I'm trying to get it into this shape:

[image]

I've seen this solution [Multi Column Pivot SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19802361/multi-column-pivot-sql-server) but it uses hardcoding values, which is not my case, hence I think it would be safer to use dynamic pivot.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Your subject references two different databases, Oracle and SQL Server.  Your tags reference only one.  You talk about wanting a dynamic pivot which implies that you want the number of columns in the result to change based on the data but you don't actually state that.  Doing a dynamic pivot would imply that you'd build the appropriate SQL statement in PL/SQL and/or T-SQL and execute it which would mean that you'd need completely different solutions for the two databases.  Is that acceptable or are you trying to find a single solution that works for both?

Comment: 1. I have the same problem to solve on two separate databases, that's why I m asking about both dbs

Comment: 2. agree probably for this exact example dynamic pivot is overkill - but I don't know how many ranked cities can there be, maybe 2 maybe 100 - hence looking for a solution with dynamic pivot

Comment: Dynamic pivot is difficult to debug. Doing it on rownumber is not dynamic and should be fairly straightforward, there are many examples of it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting the top 6 items in a column to pivot to a row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887600/getting-the-top-6-items-in-a-column-to-pivot-to-a-row-in-sql)

Comment: Why did you replace the text of your data and results with images?  Including text data in your question is strongly preferred over using images.  Is there some upper bound on the number of ranked cities?  If so, you could have a static pivot which is generally easier to deal with than a dynamic solution.  If you do want a dynamic solution, are you fine with completely different solutions for Oracle and SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id_card_no,
       max(case when city_rank = 1 then city end) as city_1,
       max(case when city_rank = 1 then visitratio end) as visitratio_1,
       max(case when city_rank = 2 then city end) as city_2,
       max(case when city_rank = 2 then visitratio end) as visitratio_2
from t
group by id_card_no;
```

This is standard SQL and should work in any database.