# group row and add column

Tags: sql

i'm struggling with a sql query to group line into colum

for example i get a table like taht

| order_id | item | amount | customer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Keyboard | 400 | 4 |
| 2 | Mouse | 300 | 4 |
| 3 | Monitor | 12000 | 3 |
| 4 | Keyboard | 400 | 1 |
| 5 | Mousepad | 250 | 2 |

and i try to add all line for same customer into one line for example

| order_id | item | amount | customer_id | item | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Keyboard | 400 | 4 | Mouse | 300 |
| 3 | Monitor | 12000 | 3 |  |  |
| 4 | Keyboard | 400 | 1 |  |  |
| 5 | Mousepad | 250 | 2 |  |  |

as i can have up to 5 row for the same key (here customer_id) i'm struggle to write the sql query.

the group by reduce the array, but not append "row detail" to column

any hint ?

Thanks

Comment: Assign row numbers, pivot columns like in this question: [Getting the top 6 items in a column to pivot to a row in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887600/getting-the-top-6-items-in-a-column-to-pivot-to-a-row-in-sql) for example. In this case it is: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KwXGwUg-).

Comment: awesome ! work as expected thanks